# NativeScript build ios big size .ipa

Tags: telerik, nativescript

This command generate a 80 mb .IPA file :

```
tns build ios --for-device --release --bundle webpack --provision [Development Profile]
```

or this one generate a 37 mb .IPA file :

```
tns build ios --for-device --release --bundle webpack --provision [Distribution Profile]
```

Why this unexpected behavior ?

Comment: Did you try this `tns build ios --release --bundle --env.aot --env.uglify`?

Comment: Could you be able to figure out why this happen?

Comment: @VahidNajafi opened an issue here https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/3850 if u can mention urself on that also